# Android Trying to Save Image Blob/Byte into CSV

Tags: android, csv

> I'm trying to save image blob/byte in CSV.
>
> Is that possible to save an image blob to CSV ?

Comment: Best approach is to base64 encode it.

Comment: then if i encode it in base64 so can i insert it in CSV ?

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't you?

Comment: Okay I'll try . I've tried to compressed using ByteArrayOutputStream but it shows an error :( .. hope that your suggestion work :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to compress it, it would defeat the purpose of base64 conversion